ggplot: how to plot points using both color and shape with two different legends
I want to plot using color for LAB and shape for AMT
df = data.frame(xdat=c(20, 40, 75, 90),
           ydat=c(2, 5, 10, 20),
           LAB=c("PM1", "PM1", "PM2", "PM2"),
           AMT=c(0.04, 1, 0.04, 4))
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=xdat,y=ydat,color=LAB)) + geom_point(size=3)

Of course this generates a figure with a LAB legend only, one color for PM1 and one color for PM2. This is fine, but I want the figure to also include a shape based on AMT. So for this example, there would be three shapes, one for each unique AMT value, where the color of the shape would match that of PM1 or PM2. Then, there would be two legends for the figure - one for LAB (two colors for PM1 and PM2) and one for AMT (three shapes for 0.04, 1, and 4).
I tried including shape in ggplot(aes(x=xdat,y=ydat,color=LAB,shape=AMT)) + geom_point(size=3) but this does not work.

And that : df %>%     ggplot(aes(x=xdat,y=ydat,color=LAB)) + geom_point(size=3, shape=df$AMT) ?

You could also use  ggplot(df, aes(x=xdat,y=ydat,color=LAB, shape = AMT)) +      geom_point() +     scale_shape_binned()

Or convert to a discrete variable, i.e. try shape=factor(AMT).

Rather than just saying "it does not work", give the specific errors you get with your code. In this case it seems to make it pretty clear what's wrong. Since AMT is numeric, it's treated as continuous and you can't assign shapes to continuous values. You can make the variable discrete by using factor: for example ggplot(df, aes(x=xdat,y=ydat,color=LAB,shape=factor(AMT))) + geom_point(size=3)

Since you are using the tidyverse, pipe to mutate(AMT = factor(AMT)). This avoids having the legend with factor in it like @stefan's and @MrFlick's otherwise good suggestion does.

Thank you all for your comments - I now understand that we can't assign shapes to continuous values.

ggplot(df, aes(x=xdat,y=ydat,color=LAB,shape=factor(AMT))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_shape(name = "AMT") # to control legend name

(Or change to factor upstream as @Rui-barradas suggested.)

